how to inherit ASP.Net WebForm MasterPage from both System.Web.UI.MasterPage And System.Web.UI.Page
how to inherit ASP.Net WebForm MasterPage from both System.Web.UI.MasterPage And System.Web.UI.Page
Please help me if anyone knows
I have a project
I want to create a master page where all the front and backend codes will be built and other pages will inherit from it.
